# Implementation of tensor product formula

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming, splines

For the Bézier surface, which owns the following *matrix definition*:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf S(u,v)&=\sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n \mathbf P_{i,j} B_{m,i}(u) B_{n,j}(v)\\
&=\small \begin{pmatrix}B_{m,0}(u)&\cdots&B_{m,m}(u)\end{pmatrix}_{1\times(m+1)}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf P_{0,0}&\cdots&\mathbf P_{0,n}\\
P_{1,0}&\cdots&\mathbf P_{1,n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\mathbf P_{m,0}&\cdots&\mathbf P_{m,n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
B_{n,0}(v)\\B_{n,1}(v)\\
\vdots\\
B_{n,n}(v)
\end{pmatrix}_{(n+1)\times 1}
\end{align*}$$

where, $B_{n,i}(u)$ is Bernstein basis.

```
vec1 = {B[0],...,B[m]};
mat = {{P[0,0],...P[0,n]},...,{P[m,0],...P[m,n]}};
vec2 = {B[0],...,B[n]};

bez = vec1.mat1.vec2
```

However, the $P_{i,j}$ is the coordinate of a 3D point, which own this style:`{x,y,z}`. So I cannot use `vec1.mat1.vec2` directly.

An alternative method is using `Hold[]` to unevaluate the coordinate `{x,y,z}`. Namely, `Hold[{x,y,z}]`. Lastly, with the help of `ReleaseHold[]` to evaluate the expression.

```
vec1 = {B[0],...,B[m]};
mat = Map[Hold,{{P[0,0],...P[0,n]},...,{P[m,0],...P[m,n]}},{2}];
vec2 = {B[0],...,B[n]};

bez = vec1.mat1.vec2 // ReleaseHold
```

Another way that I came up with is

```
vec1.mat[[All, All, #]].vec2 & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

#### Comparison

```
Bernstein[0, 0, u_?NumericQ] := 1
Bernstein[n_, i_, u_?NumericQ] := Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i)

BezierSurface2[pts_, u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{m, n, AllBasis},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[pts, 2];
  AllBasis =
   Function[{deg, u0}, Bernstein[deg, #, u0] & /@ Range[0, deg]];
  With[{row = AllBasis[m - 1, u], col = AllBasis[n - 1, v]}, 
   row.Map[Hold, pts, {2}].col // ReleaseHold]
  ]

BezierSurface1[pts_, u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{m, n, AllBasis},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[pts, 2];
  AllBasis =
   Function[{deg, u0}, Bernstein[deg, #, u0] & /@ Range[0, deg]];
  With[{row = AllBasis[m - 1, u], col = AllBasis[n - 1, v]}, 
   row.pts[[All, All, #]].col & /@ {1, 2, 3}]
]
```

---

```
cpts = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
ParametricPlot3D[
 BezierSurface1[cpts, u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming

ParametricPlot3D[
 BezierSurface2[cpts, u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming

f = BezierFunction[cpts];
ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: plots]

So my question: is there a **more efficient** method to implement this formula?

Comment: I accepted the J.M.'s answer because it is a general strategy to define `CAGDBezierFunction[]`. In addition, I will award the bounty to xzczd owns to that it is the first answer and his `Transpose[]` and `Listable` method is very useful for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might help you get an idea:

```
n = 4;
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            cpts = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, n + 1}, {j, n + 1}]];

GraphicsRow[{ParametricPlot3D[BezierFunction[cpts][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
                              Evaluated -> True], (* built-in function *)
             ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Fold[#2.#1 &, cpts, (* using dot-products *)
                                            {BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], u],
                                             BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], v]}]],
                              {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image: can you spot any difference?]

You can of course replace `BernsteinBasis[]` with your own `Bernstein[]`; no need for `Hold[]` trickery!

Comment: Thanks a lot(^_^).Nice to use the `BernsteinBasis[]` **listable** attribute and `Fold[#1.#2 &, pts, {row,col}]` strategy.

Comment: @Shutao, in this simple case, you can of course just do `col.(row.pts)`; the `Fold[]` approach becomes useful when you start considering $n$-dimensional Bézier hypersurfaces.

Comment: @J.M. I have implemented the Bezier curve and surface in my CAGD package via *The NURBS Book*. Did you know the definition of $n$-dimentional Bezier hypersurface？The built-in `BezierFunction[]` owns the below usage：`f=BezierFunction[RandomReal[1,{5,5,5,1}]]`.However,I didn't know its definition.

Comment: @Shutao, well, if you have, say, the 4D case, with a set of control points represented by a $p\times q\times r\times 4$ list, you just plug this list into the second argument of `Fold[]`, and then the third argument is something like `{BernsteinBasis[p - 1, Range[0, p - 1], u], BernsteinBasis[q - 1, Range[0, q - 1], v], BernsteinBasis[r - 1, Range[0, r - 1], w]}`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot. Got it. For the curve case, the control-points owns dimention：$n \times i$, where $i=2,3,4$. For the surface case, the control nets owns dimention :$m \times n \times i$.

Comment: Rencently, I discovered that `Fold[#2.#1 &, cpts, {BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], u], BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], v]}]` cannot be compiled with the *built-in* `Compile[]`. A workarounds is using `BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], v].(BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], u].cpts)`. Please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108119/how-to-optimize-my-own-bezierfunction/119545#119545)

Comment: @Shutao, certainly; `BernsteinBasis[]` isn't a compilable function. If you want something compilable, you will have to implement de Casteljau manually.

Comment: @Shutao, you should have commented here instead. Anyway: this is a *tensor* being multiplied with a bunch of vectors until you obtain a scalar result. I have not done C in a while, and I'm not sure how you can manage a $k$-dimensional array of pointers without some external library.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, maybe I need to seek the external library about tensor calculation.:) In addition, I know the LibraryLink  deal with *tensor* as a flatten $1$-array.

Comment: @J.M. Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ff2O3.png)

Answer (score 11):

### Update

Fully compiling the code to C makes it as fast as the built-in:

```
cBernstein = 
 Compile @@ (Hold[{n, {j, _Real, 1}, u}, Table[expr u^i (1 - u)^(n - i), {i, j}], 
     CompilationTarget -> C] /. expr -> FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, i]])

BezierSurface4 = 
  With[{cBernstein = cBernstein}, 
   With[{AllBasis = Function[{deg, u0}, cBernstein[deg, Range[0, deg], u0]]}, 
    Compile[{{pts, _Real, 3}, u, v}, Module[{m, n}, {m, n} = Dimensions[pts, 2];
      
      With[{row = AllBasis[m - 1, u], col = AllBasis[n - 1, v]}, 
       row.Transpose[pts, {1, 3, 2}].col]], 
     RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
     CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
     CompilationTarget -> C]]];

f = BezierFunction[cpts];
ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.018014, Null} *)

ParametricPlot3D[BezierSurface4[cpts, u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.018006, Null} *)
```

---

### Old Answer

`Compile` and `Transpose` and `Listable` will help:

```
cBernstein = 
 Compile[{n, {i, _Real, 1}, u}, 
  Evaluate[FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, i]] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i)]]

BezierSurface3[pts_, u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{m, n, AllBasis}, {m, n} = Dimensions[pts, 2];
  AllBasis = Function[{deg, u0}, cBernstein[deg, Range[0, deg], u0]];
  With[{row = AllBasis[m - 1, u], col = AllBasis[n - 1, v]}, 
   row.Transpose[pts, {1, 3, 2}].col]]

ParametricPlot3D[BezierSurface1[cpts, u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.219170, Null} *)
ParametricPlot3D[BezierSurface3[cpts, u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.098571, Null} *)
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, the OP did *not* make it clear why he wanted to re-implement a built-in function. Yes, I can read what he asked for—but he did not explain *why*. Since your code is only as fast as the built-in code (not surprisingly—it would be really impressive if it was faster), the only reason he could have would be to implement something *closely related that is not built-in*.

Comment: As I show in my answer, you don't even need to transpose; you just have to perform the multiplications in a different order.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, you're right, `row.Transpose[pts, {1, 3, 2}].col` can be further simplified to `col.(row.pts)` in this case, the speed improvement is negligible though. (`Transpose` is so fast. )