# How to optimize my own BezierFunction?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, visualization, splines

A few months ago, I asked a question about the implementation of Bezier surface. Please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104463/implementation-of-a-matrix-formula) for a full detail.

I also know that `BezierFunction[]` is *built-in* in Wolfram Language.

> `BezierFunction`[*array*]
>
> represents a Bézier function for a surface or high-dimensional manifold.

Owing to that I have been learning the NURBS theory, and I have implemented a variety of algorithms in my package `CAGD`.

Here, thanks for J.M.'s explanation about [the definition of high-dimensional Bezier function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104463/implementation-of-a-matrix-formula/107843?noredirect=1#comment291777_107843).

So I implemented the `CAGDBezierFunction[]` as follows:

```
CAGDBezierFunction[array_, dim_][args__] :=
 Fold[
  #2.#1 &, array,
  BernsteinBasis[#1, Range[0, #1], #2] & @@@ Thread@{dim, {args}}]

CAGDBezierFunction[array_] :=
 CAGDBezierFunction[array, Most@Dimensions[array] - 1]

pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 10, 2, 1}];
BezierFunction[pts][0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
CAGDBezierFunction[pts][0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
(*{0.701598}*)
```

However, when I visualize this function via `ContourPlot3D[]`, it is very time-consuming.

```
f = BezierFunction[pts]
ContourPlot3D[f[u, v, w], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[
 CAGDBezierFunction[pts, {9, 9, 1}][u, v, w], 
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

So my question is :

- Is it possible to optimize the user-defined function `CAGDBezierFunction[]`?
- <s>Is the programming language of *Mathematica* a high performance language?</s>

---

**Update**:

Thanks for bill s's [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108119/how-to-optimize-my-own-bezierfunction?noredirect=1#comment305881_108119): `PlotPoints -> 3`

[image]

Comment: What happens if you set `Evaluated -> True` in your second `ContourPlot3D`?

Comment: @J.M. I cannot achieve the graph when it ran for 5 min:(

Comment: You can speed it up quite a bit by using fewer starting points, i.e., using `PlotPoints -> 3` speeds it up by a factor of about 20.

Comment: @bills Thanks a bunch. It is very useful:)

Comment: And faster yet again with PlotPoints -> 2. I don't think it can go down to 1.

Comment: @bills According to my test, `PlotPoints -> 3` will loss a bit of graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a comparison of your function (adequately post-processed via `PiecewiseExpand[]` and `Expand[]`) compiled to `"C"` and `"WVM"` with `` System`BezierFunction[] ``:

```
exs = Join[{#, 
      Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, 
       Evaluate[Expand@PiecewiseExpand[CAGDBezierFunction[pts][x, y, z], 
                                       Thread[0 < {x, y, z} < 1]]], 
       CompilationTarget -> #, RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False]} & /@ 
       {"C", "WVM"}, {{System, BezierFunction[pts]}}];

Grid[Join[{{"Timing", "Result"}}, 
  Timing@ContourPlot3D[#[[2]][u, v, w], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}, 
                       Mesh -> None, PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] & /@ exs], 
  Frame -> All]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

`RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False` was suggested by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) in a (now deleted) comment.