# Convert parametric to cartesian

Tags: parametric-functions, splines

I'm drawing a Bézier surface.

```
f = BezierFunction[pts]
Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Small], Red, Point /@ pts, Green}], 
     ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]]
```

How can I convert parametric function to Cartesian ($(u,v)$ to $(x,y)$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy outlined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107843) can be used to generate the Cartesian equation, with the help of `GroebnerBasis[]`. To wit,

```
pts = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 3, 0}, {0, 4, 0}},
       {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0}, {1, 4, 1}},
       {{2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 4, 0}},
       {{3, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 0}, {3, 3, 0}, {3, 4, 1}}};

{m, n} = Most[Dimensions[pts]] - 1;

bf = BezierFunction[pts];

bf2[u_, v_] = PiecewiseExpand[Fold[#2.#1 &, pts,
                                   {BernsteinBasis[m, Range[0, m], u], 
                                    BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], v]}],
                              {0 < u < 1 && 0 < v < 1}];

cart[x_, y_] = z /. First @ Solve[First[
     GroebnerBasis[Thread[{x, y, z} == bf2[u, v]], {x, y, z}, {u, v}]] == 0, z]
   (6912 x y - 2304 x^2 y - 2592 x y^2 + 864 x^2 y^2 + 81 x y^4 - 36 x^2 y^4 +
    4 x^3 y^4)/6912

{Plot3D[cart[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, BoxRatios -> Automatic], 
 ParametricPlot3D[bf[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: explicit versus parametric form]

Comment: The problem is that I have ~1000 points and it takes realy long time.

Comment: Then what's the point of converting to Cartesian? It is more convenient to keep it in parametric form in that case.